# getElementById with onInput in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, babeljs

I'm fairly new to React and I'm trying to figure out how to add a small function that helps me style a slider component. I'm currently using `getElementById` and `onInput`. I have found similar questions but all of them reference `onClick` events which I'm not trying to do. Hopefully I'm not terribly far off here! Any help is appreciated. Here's the relevant parts of my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#myinput {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
  border: solid 1px #82CFD0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  width: 356px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

JS(Babel):

```
class VolumeSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 120.5
    };
  }

  onUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }

document.getElementById("myinput").oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 ' + this.state.value + '%, #fff ' + this.state.value + '%, white 100%)'
};

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mb1">
        <input
          className="c-input--range"
          list="tickmarks"
          max={1200}
          onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate(e)}
          step={0.1}
          type="range"
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <div>
           <label className="c-label">{this.state.value}c</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <VolumeSlider />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, can you provide more details?

Comment: Not sure what your asking, your code is using neither getElementById nor onInput

Comment: Hi! I am trying to edit the input range to have color on the left side, but not the right. Here's my codepen to give you a better idea. I'm sorry I just realized my origional question didn't include all of my code, just edited it to fix that. https://codepen.io/kcandle/pen/qBNLMQE

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are not using the same logic used for `onUpdate`?

```
onInput(e){
  e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%,  #82CFD0 ' + this.state.value + '%, #fff ' + this.state.value + '%, white 100%)';
}
```

```js
class VolumeSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 120.5
    };
  }

  onUpdate(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  }
 
  onInput(e){
    const gradStart = (this.state.value/e.target.max/2)*100;
    const gradEnd = (this.state.value/e.target.max)*100;
    e.target.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%,  #82CFD0 ' + gradStart + '%, #fff ' + gradEnd + '%, white 50%)';
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      
      <div className="mb1">
        <input
          className="c-input--range"
          id="myinput"
          list="tickmarks"
          max={1200}
          onChange={(e) => this.onUpdate(e)}
          onInput={(e) => this.onInput(e)}
          step={0.1}
          type="range"
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <div>
           <label className="c-label">{this.state.value}c</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <VolumeSlider />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
#myinput {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 50%, #eee 50%, #eee 100%);
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  width: 356px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a template, does that look like what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the update! I was trying to do this without loosing the right side of the range input or the gradient from left to right before the thumb. Basically, I was trying to make the bar fill normally, for some reason this is a bit more difficult than I thought haha.

Comment: Hi again, so I've updated this to look a little  more like what I'm going for. But for some reason the slider has become super choppy and won't update on click. Any ideas? https://codepen.io/kcandle/pen/qBNLMQE